# I want to save the frames of video at certain time intervals using python opencv module

Tags: python, video-capture, opencv

I want to save the frames of video at certain time intervals using python opencv module.

I have to divide the video file into 40 images.
But I do not think of algorithms.

My Idea is:

1. Input Video File.
2. Counts the number of frames and fps in a video.
3. Returns the spacing between frames. (length / 40)
4. Run while

The way of Counting the num of frames, fps and jump interval:

```
length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

After Counting the number of frame, fps and jump(Example):

```
D:\UCF-101\ApplyEyeMakeup\v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g01_c01.avi's FPS :  25.0
D:\UCF-101\ApplyEyeMakeup\v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g01_c01.avi's Length :  164
D:\UCF-101\ApplyEyeMakeup\v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g01_c01.avi's Running time :  6.56
D:\UCF-101\ApplyEyeMakeup\v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g01_c01.avi's jump :  4 ( 4.1 )
```

and here is while loop:

```
while count < length and save < 40:
    print("Count : ", count)
    success, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Window', frame)
    if count % jump == 0:
        cv2.imwrite(save_path + LabelList[LabelNumber] + "\\" + FileList[FileNumber] + "_" + str(count) + ".jpg", frame)
        save = save + 1
        print("Saved! : ", save)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    count = count + 1
```

And I faced two problems:

1. A video with a total length of less than 30 frames
2. There is not frame like **3.25 frame**(there is just 3 frame, not float number)

Anyway, If you are interested in my problem, I will teach you in detail.
I do not know what to say.

The important thing is that I want to save 40 images at regular intervals regardless of the length of the image.

Please help me bro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is not frame like 3.25 frame(there is just 3 frame, not float number)

If you make `jump` a float, then just change your condition to `count % jump < 1`. You will get uneven spacings between the frames, but should end up with 40 frames in each case.

> A video with a total length of less than 30 frames.

Just set `jump` to 1 if the number of frames is <= 40, and you will get all available frames.

Comment: In second problem, If I set **jump = 1**, Then I can only get 30 Images. I need exactly 40 Images.

Comment: What is your goal in producing 40 frames. Do you want to repeat some of the frames? Do you want to interpolate the frames? Could you just repeat the last frame until you hit 40? It's not clear from the question

Comment: Thank you for answering! I gave up extracting images from that videos!

Answer (score 0):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vidoname)

time_skips = float(2000) #skip every 2 seconds. You need to modify this

count = 0
success,image = cap.read()
while success:
    cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,(count*time_skips))    # move the time
    success,image = cap.read()
    count += 1

# release after reading    
cap.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

***IF YOU WANT TO GET FRAMES FOR PARTICULAR INTERVAL***

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("E:\\VID-20190124-WA0016.mp4")

count = 0

while cap.isOpened():

ret, frame = cap.read()

if ret:
    cv2.imwrite('D:\\out2\\frame{:d}.jpg'.format(count), frame)
    count += 30 # i.e. at 30 fps, this advances one second
    cap.set(1, count)
else:
    cap.release()
    break
```